# How to import JPEG file in MS SQL server?

Tags: sql

I want to insert jpeg file in SQL. How to do this?

Comment: into a table? what DBMS are you using? give as much Information as you can, we know nothing about your problem

Comment: A general answer is to use BLOG type to store such data. However, the way to import/insert such data varies from dbms to dbms.

Comment: @tibetty Did you mean to type BLOB?

Comment: @yanman1234 thanks for your correction and sorry for the typo. Yes, I mean it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the `binary`, `varbinary` or `varbinary(max)` [data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/binary-and-varbinary-transact-sql).

Of course, you have to convert the (JPEG) image to a byte array first in order to store it in the database. Depending on the programming language of your choice this can be easy or hard. 
Not sure if you can read files from a T-SQL command and store/retrieve them from a database. Then again, I don't think you would want such a scenario in real-life.